# Aggregate function SUM() for money

Tags: mysql

Requirement is add salary of employee i m using SUM() , salary is in this format `1,00,005.00` so when `1,00,005.00 + 3,00,005.00` it gives result as 4 not actual result , 
this is query ---->

```
SELECT employee.name, SUM( department.salary ) AS Salary
 FROM department
 LEFT JOIN employee ON department.employee_id = employee.id
 GROUP BY name
```

Comment: What is the type of salary field?

Comment: @sectus data type is `varchar`

Comment: Numbers don't have commas in them..... if you're saving this in a varchar with the commas, then stop doing so..... convert your field to a numeric and store a value without those commas

Comment: @SoftwareDev, so, how values got there?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all "," in salary and then use sum(). you can use mysql [replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function

```
SELECT employee.name, SUM( replace(department.salary,",","") ) AS
Salary  FROM department  LEFT JOIN employee ON department.employee_id
= employee.id  GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

The main question is whether your currency is a decimal type or not. Your format "1,00,005.00" with groups of two **and** three digit makes me wonder.

If it is, if "1,99,997" + "0,00,003" is equal to "2,00,000", then you can use Hắc Huyền Minh's answer and convert it to a decimal equivalent straight away.

**Before doing that**, though, I would run an acceptance test on the database to verify that all values are indeed in the form you expect. Otherwise you might introduce a bug in the workings. `VARCHAR` type has no validation whatsoever, and someone could have a salary of "1,0X,000.15" which would be considered equivalent to *ten* after the conversion.

If your currency is **not** a decimal type - for example if "1,05,03" means "[one pound five shilling three pennies](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_sterling#The_old_system)" - then "1,05,03" + "1,19,09" is *not* "2,24,12" but rather "3,05,00" - since twelve pennies, not ten, make a shilling, and it takes twenty shillings to make a pound.

In this case you either convert it to decimal via weighting, or you select all the rows and do the sum in code instead of in MySQL. It would be possible also to implement a UDF to perform either the sum or the conversion to decimal.

For weighting, you consider that if one pound is made up of 20 shillings, then each shilling is 1/20 of one pound, and so equals 0.05; so "1,05" becomes 1 + 5*0.05 = 1.25. For pennies, twelve pennies make one shilling which is 0.05 pounds, so one penny is 0.05/12 = 0.00416666... (and there you see a difficulty. You will need a larger numeric type to prevent numeric errors from creeping in).

Comment: Read [*Indian Numbering System*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Numbering_System)

Comment: I see. That's good news for the OP - @HắcHuyềnMinh's answer should work. Only be sure to run acceptance tests, just in case. (Also, it seems to me it would be more practical to store values as currency types, and only format them on display).